# Proving that a certain function is well-defined

Tags: integration

I would like to know how I prove that the map
$$T:C([0,1])\rightarrow C^1([0,1])$$ $$(Tf)(s):=\int_0^sf(t)dt$$
is well-defined.

I suspect that proving $Ran(T)\subset C^1([0,1])$ would be enough. Is this true?

For this I would start with an $f\in Ran(T)$, i.e. of the form $f(s)=(Tg)(s)=\int_0^sg(t)dt$ for some $g\in C([0,1])$. How do I prove this is continuously differentiable though?

Help would be very welcome.

Comment: For $T$ to be well defined you need to show that $Tf$ is a continuously differentiable function for any continuous $f$. I.e. $Tf\in C^1[0,1]$ for any $f\in C[0,1]$. But this is implied by the fundamental theorem of calculus as the answers below indicate.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental theorem of calculus tells you that

$$
f'(s) = (Tg)' (s) = g(s).
$$

Comment: Does this make the function well-defined, too?

Comment: Yes, it does. You might want to look at this q/a for a better understanding of what "well-defined" actually means: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606917/well-defined-function-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are theorems which tell you when $s\mapsto \int_0^s f(t) dt $ is differentiable. For continuous $f$ this happens to be true, and the derivative is known to be 
$$ \frac{d}{ds}\int_0^s f(t) dt = f(s)$$
which is continuous by assumption.

Comment: And does this prove that the function is well-defined?

Comment: @see yes ${\,\,\,\,}$