# Determine if a function is well defined or not

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

I am doing some mathematics, and I am currently stuck on something. I do not understand this part at all, how can two slightly, minor different functions, but near identical—evaluate so differently.

**Exercises:**
[image]

**Do not understand part:**

$$(a)\enspace f:R\to R, f(x)=\frac{x}{3},\enspace \it{Well\enspace Defined} $$
$$(b)\enspace g:J\to J, g(x)=\frac{x}{3},\enspace \it{Not\enspace well\enspace defined} $$

**Why is $(a)$ well defined, whereas, $(b)$ is not?**

Interesting explanation found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313169/how-do-i-prove-that-a-function-is-well-defined), however, I cannot get any smarter.

**Reference:**

- *Discrete Mathematics for Computing, 3rd Edition by Peter Grossman*

**EDIT 8/1/2023 4:50 PM** Clarity. $R$ and $J$ are **sets**.

**EDIT: 8/1/2023 5:25 PM** From the book:

- $N$ is the set of natural numbers (or positive integers): $\{1,2,3,4,...\}$.
- $J$ is the set of integers: $\{...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...\}$.
- $Q$ is the set of rational numbers: $\{x:x=m/n\enspace for\enspace some\enspace integers\enspace m\enspace and\enspace n\}$.
- $R$ is the set of real numbers.

Comment: What is $J$ in this question?

Comment: Find $x\in J$ such that $x/3\notin J$. Can't say much else without knowing what $J$ is.

Comment: @ChrisLewis, please see the photo, it comes from my Book. I haven't created the `J` or `R` in this context. They exists in the **Exercises** section.

Comment: I've seen $J$ used to denote the positive integers. I've not sure if that's the case here, but if it were, notice that the second function wouldn't be well-defined. For example, we'd have $g(2) = \frac{2}{3}$, which is definitely not a positive integer, so the codomain of that function wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @Cardinality, you are the only one making sense to me now. *Can you please, please expand and elaborate on this? Please kindly.*

Comment: Look earlier in your book for the correct definition of $J$. You've written $J=\{\}$, but that doesn't make sense.

Comment: For a function $f: A \to B$ to be well-defined,  it must be the case that for every $a \in A$, there exists a unique $b \in B$ with $f(a) = b$. There are two ways this can go wrong immediately. First, it might be that we're trying to send some $a \in A$ to two distinct elements of $B$: that's not allowed. Second, it may be that the rule attempts to an assign an element of $a$ to an element outside of $B$. In the case above, $J$ consists only of the positive integers, but $\frac{2}{3}$ is most certainly not a positive integer. The function isn't well-defined because the codomain doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\bf{J}$ is Grossman's notation for the set of positive and negative integers (see beginning of the chapter on sets). So obviously $g$ isn't well-defined over that set!

Comment: Thanks. Why isn't `g()` well defined over that particular set?

Comment: Not all integers are divisible by 3 are they?

Comment: Of course not, so, essentially, the assumption is that when you perform division over the *denominator* 3, you should end up with a reminder of $1$, denoting that the *numerator* is correct one. So, the set $R$ in this context does that, where as, $J$ does not because of what you wrote.

Comment: Peter, am I correct in my thought here? See previous comment from me.

Comment: You are overthinking. A correctly defined function $g\colon J \to J$ will for any input from $J$ OUTPUT A VALUE IN $J$. Trivially division by three doesn't do that over the integers.